# 2019: Trending our answered percentage ranking to 1st (currently 18th)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I'd like to track this with the goal of getting the answer rate up to 100% (with rounding, at least), and our rank site-wide at 1st for answering, and as such will occasionally update below with updated stats.  Feel free to do this as well.

At time of writing (May 6, 2019) we have:

- [795 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [705 questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- a [98%ish answer rate, which puts us at 31st overall](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) on the network

Let's get cracking and answer / process / deal with as many as we can!

Comment: We are the highest ranked (in terms of answer percentage) with more than 20 new questions per day!

Answer (score 11):

Update answer below with the following:

- [date of update](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current%20time%20utc) **(Date)**
- [# questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) **(NoVotes)**
- [# questions with no answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) **(NoAnswers)**
- [% answered rate](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) on the network **(%Answered)**
- [rank for answered rate](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) on the network **(Rank)**

```
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Date                 | NoVotes | NoAnswers | %Answered | Rank   |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+   
| Nov 26, 2019         |   605   |   602     |    98%    |  18th  |     
| Nov 25, 2019         |   600   |   597     |    98%    |  18th  |     
| Nov 22, 2019         |   597   |   593     |    98%    |  18th  |     
| Nov 21, 2019         |   605   |   600     |    98%    |  19th  |     
| Nov 20, 2019         |   625   |   618     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Nov 19, 2019         |   633   |   627     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Nov 18, 2019         |   637   |   630     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Nov 13, 2019         |   635   |   623     |    98%    |  19th  |     
| Nov 12, 2019         |   642   |   635     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Nov 11, 2019         |   644   |   636     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Nov 08, 2019         |   644   |   634     |    98%    |  19th  |     
| Oct 31, 2019         |   641   |   635     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Oct 30, 2019         |   644   |   637     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Oct 25, 2019         |   644   |   638     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 24, 2019         |   645   |   639     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 23, 2019         |   649   |   641     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 21, 2019         |   657   |   649     |    98%    |  20th  |     
| Oct 18, 2019         |   659   |   650     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 15, 2019         |   658   |   651     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 11, 2019         |   658   |   652     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 08, 2019         |   663   |   656     |    98%    |  21st  |     
| Oct 05, 2019         |   669   |   660     |    98%    |  22nd  |     
| Oct 01, 2019         |   674   |   669     |    98%    |  22nd  |     
| Sep 30, 2019         |   683   |   671     |    98%    |  23rd  |     
| Sep 26, 2019         |   682   |   676     |    98%    |  23rd  |     
| Sep 25, 2019         |   689   |   684     |    98%    |  24th  |     
| Sep 24, 2019         |   687   |   683     |    98%    |  24th  |     
| Sep 23, 2019         |   699   |   693     |    98%    |  24th  |     
| Sep 20, 2019         |   699   |   694     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 16, 2019         |   726   |   725     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 14, 2019         |   734   |   734     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 13, 2019         |   739   |   738     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 12, 2019         |   747   |   747     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 11, 2019         |   754   |   754     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 10, 2019         |   757   |   757     |    98%    |  25th  |     
| Sep 06, 2019         |   786   |   785     |    98%    |  28th  | 
| Sep 05, 2019         |   798   |   791     |    98%    |  28th  | 
| Sep 04, 2019         |   798   |   796     |    98%    |  26th  | 
| Sep 02, 2019         |   811   |   807     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 30, 2019         |   810   |   807     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 27, 2019         |   819   |   811     |    98%    |  30th  | 
| Aug 26, 2019         |   825   |   816     |    98%    |  30th  | 
| Aug 21, 2019         |   813   |   798     |    98%    |  28th  | 
| Aug 20, 2019         |   811   |   795     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 16, 2019         |   822   |   808     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 14, 2019         |   831   |   818     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 12, 2019         |   828   |   813     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 07, 2019         |   837   |   821     |    98%    |  29th  | 
| Aug 06, 2019         |   846   |   831     |    98%    |  30th  | 
| Aug 05, 2019         |   875   |   855     |    98%    |  31st  | 
| Aug 02, 2019         |   889   |   868     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jul 25, 2019         |   899   |   883     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jul 17, 2019         |   888   |   868     |    98%    |  33rd  | 
| Jul 09, 2019         |   871   |   854     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jul 05, 2019         |   847   |   830     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jul 02, 2019         |   839   |   821     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jun 28, 2019         |   833   |   811     |    98%    |  32nd  | 
| Jun 27, 2019         |   840   |   814     |    98%    |  32nd  |  
| Jun 24, 2019         |   831   |   796     |    98%    |  32nd  |  
| Jun 18, 2019         |   800   |   770     |    98%    |  30th  |
| May 27, 2019         |   690   |   672     |    98%    |  26th  |
| May 23, 2019         |   679   |   661     |    98%    |  26th  |
| May 17, 2019         |   656   |   642     |    98%    |  27th  |
| May 16, 2019         |   674   |   654     |    98%    |  27th  |
| May 14, 2019         |   688   |   670     |    98%    |  29th  |
| May 13, 2019         |   700   |   683     |    98%    |  28th  |
| May 6, 2019          |   795   |   705     |    98%    |  31st  |
+----------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```